# Replace value for both lists and dicts

Tags: python-3.x

Can this behaviour be replicated using a cleaner solution? I would prefer a pretty one-liner, but that might not be possible.

*Wrapping this wrapper doesn't count*

The program **MUST** give an error when the key or index doesn't exist.

```py
def replace(obj, key, value):
    try:
        obj[key] # assure existance
        obj[key] = value
        print(obj)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
replace([0], 0, 1)
replace({"a": 0}, "a", 1)
replace([], 0, 1)
replace({}, "a", 1)
```

Output:

```
[1]
{'a': 1}
IndexError('list index out of range')
KeyError('a')
```

I currently have this thanks to @Iain Shelvington:

```py
def replace(o, k, v):
    try:
        o[k] = o[k] and False or v
        print(o)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

And this other hacky solution, which is only technically smaller:

```py
def replace(o, k, v):
    try:
        o[k] = v if o[k] else v
        print(o)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

This one after the suggestion to work with tuples, which is actually OK.

```py
def replace(o, k, v):
    try:
        o[k], _ = v, o[k]
        print(o)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

And this cheat:

```py
def replace(o, k, v):
    try:
        o[k]; o[k] = v
        print(o)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it into a one liner? Writing different functions for `list`s and `dict`s are better practice than what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure why you want a one-liner or if it's a good idea but I was curious and something like this works as a one-liner `obj[key] = obj[key] and False or value`, pretty ugly...

Comment: Prettier how? Is it like a never-ending prettification?

Comment: @Nineteendo I think whatever the solution it's always going to be fairly ugly :) If line length is important then there is also this solution which is slightly smaller - `o[k] = (o[k], v)[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*That being said, I think this is the most readable solution, which shouldn't be underlined by any interpretor:*

```py
def replace(o, k, v):
    try:
        if type(o) == dict and not k in o:
            raise KeyError(k)
        o[k] = v
        print(o)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Let me know if you've a better solution.